# Can you run TeamCity 7 on an intel 2700/amd e450 based system?

Tags: intel-atom, teamcity

I am looking at setting up a cheap low power pc to run as a build server primarily, but also maybe run mongodb and mysql and iis. It would only be for my personal projects so it would not get totally battered.

Currently most systems I have seen have either an intel [D2700](http://ark.intel.com/products/59683/) or [e450](http://products.amd.com/pages/notebookapudetail.aspx?id=21&f1=&f2=&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=&&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) processor then have usually around 4gb RAM and generally 500GB SATA 5400rpm harddisk, but the size may change but not the speed.

It mentions on the teamcity site that they recommend 2ghz processors and faster hard disks are better due to the amount of IO it does, the main worry is the agent. Most of my builds will compile, run unit/integration tests, then selenium based acceptance tests.

Anyway has anyone tried getting it running on low powered systems? and if so did it run ok?

Comment: Any reason you can't step up a tiny bit - say to a modern pentium or core i3? Power efficiency on those is pretty good, and you'd have room to grow if need be, since you could use a better processor in future if your system didn't scale well. While its a guide for a kid's system, [this may be a good place to start](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/child-game-pc-build,3247.html)

Comment: I can pick any spec really, I was just trying to keep the physical size of the computer, the power usage and cost to a minimum. If I was to just go and get a full sized pc I would probably get an i5 given the price to power ratio. It is just there are quite nice tiny computers which are priced well and take up hardly any space, as I have 2 laptops for work and gaming, I just want a static computer in the office purely for building and testing on. Here are the systems I am currently looking at: http://www.ebuyer.com/store/Computer/cat/Nettop

Comment: There are other small form factors available, like '[Shuttle](http://www.ebuyer.com/search?page=1&store=2&cat=103&filtermfr=351)' which would allow you to build a machine with a spec of your choosing. Asus have their own versions too.

Comment: I did look at the shuttle and other barebone style machines, but then the cost ends up getting higher for the separate components. You are right though it is another good alternative, but we are getting off topic here, the current question is just if the atom and amd low power variants would run team city.

Comment: To add a (late) suggestion, check out the HP Proliant MicroServer line.  They're priced in the same range as a NAS enclosure but have some nice server features, like an IP-KVM tool.